# What flowering green plant is this?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I got this green plant as a gift many years ago, but I have never seen it flower before. It has a strong, pleasant scent and cool flowers so I'd really would like to know what it is.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The plants sometimes are native to a certain region. Care enough to share yours?

Comment: @bonCodigo Sure! I'm in Sweden but I'm quite certain that these are not native here :)

Comment: It is member of family Amaryllidaceae (of monocot)

Comment: also called spider lily. some other related plants also called spider lily. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_lily

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like a "Spider lily" from the [*Hymenocallis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hymenocallis) genus.

Here is a picture of *Hymenocallis caribaea* from wikipedia for comparison:
[image]

There are however ~65 species in the genus (according to wikipedia), and I cannot say exactly what species you have.